# How to track views of a section on a page

Tags: google-analytics

The content on a page varies from user to user .. e.g a loggedin user will see a section (e.g widget) on a page whereas a logged out user will not .. using google analytics how can i track number of times the section is shown on the page. The data is required to track conversion of the section.

Comment: How about tracking pageviews with custom variable for logged in users.

Answer (score 0):

You can fire up additional virtual pageview call on the load of widget if it's loaded. That will help you to identify if the widget is loaded.